# How to pass ajax response value into input field for autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want my autocomplete to auto fill the form if there were past user data. But when I keyed in i_ic_num field in the form, it does not autocomplete my form. However, the data that I pass through ajax has it response that contain other field such as s_name, i_contact_num, s_company_name and s_host. Therefore, I don't really aware where I am wrong.

```
\\\\\
<script>  
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('#i_ic_num').change( function(){  
                var i_ic_num = $(this).val();  
                url = "<?php echo base_url('index.php/visitor_new/autofill'); ?>";
                $.ajax({  
                      url,  
                      method:"POST",  
                    data:{
                           i_ic_num:$("#i_ic_num").val()
                      },  
                      async : false,
                      dataType: 'json',      
                      success: function(json)  
                         {                            
                             //$('#i_ic_num').val(json.i_ic_num);  
                             //$('#s_name').val(json.s_name);
                              //$('#i_contact_num').val(json.i_contact_num);
                                //$('#s_company_name').val(json.s_company_name);  
                          //$('#s_host').val(json.s_host);

                              var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
                               $('#s_name').val("s_name");              
                           },   
                      });  

            });

       });  



    </script>  
\\\\
```

I expect it to fill in the related field that has been call. However, it did not do what I intended.

Console

[image: Output]

Comment: `console.log(json)` in success function what is it?

Comment: nothing. But my xhr in the network output json array that I've passed from controller

Comment: can you share a picture of your dev tools network request/response?

Comment: There, I edited the post. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Had to zoom in but as far as I can see, that ain't JSON. Why does the response start with `123`?

Comment: That's what I input to trigger the function. Anyway, I already figure it out. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figure out the answer! Thank you everyone. I kept my script just as it is. And I added ob_start; at the start of my autofill function and  ob_end_clean(); right before I output my json array. It function to clear the buffer if browser were to output anything. Here I include my codes for everyone to see.

```
public function autofill(){
        ob_start();
        $i_ic_num =$this -> input -> post('i_ic_num');
                $arr_result = array();
                print_r($i_ic_num);
        if($i_ic_num <> ""){
            $this -> load -> model("visitor_new_model");
            $this -> db -> where($this -> visitor_new_model -> table.'.i_ic_num', $i_ic_num);
            $visitor_new_info = $this -> visitor_new_model -> _get_single();
            if ($visitor_new_info){

                //$arr_result['i_ic_num'] = $visitor_new_info ->i_ic_num ;  
                $arr_result['s_name'] = $visitor_new_info ->s_name ;    
                $arr_result['i_contact_num'] = $visitor_new_info->i_contact_num ;
                $arr_result['s_company_name'] = $visitor_new_info ->s_company_name ;    
                $arr_result['s_host'] = $visitor_new_info ->s_host ;    

            }

        }       
            ob_end_clean();
            echo json_encode($arr_result);
    }
```